# How not to change formular selection after onchange event

Tags: javascript, ajax

please I have some issue with JavaScript.

http://www.stud.fit.vutbr.cz/~xhrnci11/IOT/iot.php here is my website, I want that when I select eg. "Option One" after onchange event (reloading website) it stay selected "Option One" and not "Select..." instead.

How can I do something like that?

Thank you

EDIT:
my php script:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['mySelect']))
{
    $value = $_POST['mySelect'];
    if ($value == 1) {
        echo "blabla";
    }
    elseif ($value == 2) {
        echo "hello";
    }
}
```

Comment: Right now you have a script on the page setting it to the empty value: $("select option[value='']").attr("selected","selected");.  I would either set the dropdown via PHP using the form value and get rid of the JS or would change the current JS to set it to the value using PHP.  You might want to post the sample of your PHP if you need specifics on accomplishing this

Comment: @Duffmaster33 I have added my PHP script. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either set the JS:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['mySelect']))
{
    $value = $_POST['mySelect'];
echo "<script>$('select option[value=\"".$value."\"]').attr('selected', 'selected');</script>";
    if ($value == 1) {
        echo "blabla";
    }
    elseif ($value == 2) {
        echo "hello";
    }
} ?>
```

or set the HTML directly and remove the JS:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['mySelect']))
{
    $value = $_POST['mySelect'];
    if ($value == 1) {
        echo "blabla";
    }
    elseif ($value == 2) {
        echo "hello";
    }
} ?>
<select id="mySelect" name="mySelect" onchange="document.getElementById('myForm').submit();">
        <option value="" selected="selected">Select...</option>
        <option value="1" <?php if($value == "1") echo "selected"; ?>>Option One</option>
        <option value="2" <?php if($value == "2") echo "selected"; ?>>Option Two</option>
</select>
```

Comment: thank you, I have tried your JavaScript but it still don't work. Try to open link below.

Comment: Tom that's because you have a PHP error on your page.  You need to first set the value of $value (using the code snippet you provided us) and then retrieve it for one of my solutions above.  Try that out and let me know how it goes

Comment: thank you now it works awesome. May I ask you for explanation of this line of code? 
`<script>$('select option[value=\"".$value."\"]').attr('selected', 'selected');</script>` It is difficult for me understand JavaScript scripts. Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

you need to specify the selected option using php

```
<select id="mySelect" name="mySelect" onchange="document.getElementById('myForm').submit();">
        <option value="" selected="selected">Select...</option>
        <?php
        $selected1 = ($value==1)?"selected":"";
        $selected2 = ($value==2)?"selected":"";
        echo '<option value="1" '. $selected1 . ' >Option One</option>';
        echo '<option value="2" ' . $selected2 . ' >Option Two</option>';
        ?>
</select>
```

Comment: thank you @Khalid I have tried it but same result as before. You can see it in link below.

Comment: @Tom, please check update, I used same variable name for 2 variable